# Há como passar uma instancia de classe como parametro de um método em Python?

Tags: python

Estou fazendo uma implementação do algoritmo A Estrela(A*).

Minha duvida é justamente essa do título, eu venho do java e do c++, e não sei como fazer isso no python.

```
def transfTo(Bucket a): <------------Dúvida aqui!
        transf = a.total - a.current
        if current >= transf:
            a.current = a.total
            current -= transf
        else:
            a.total += current
            current = 0
```

Comment: A dúvida é se consegue passar como parâmetro ou se é possível definir a classe da instância? Lembre-se que, diferente do Java e C++, Python possui tipagem dinâmica.

Comment: Se eu consigo passar como parametro. Pq não estou conseguindo acessar os métodos e atributos da variavel "a" da classe Bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, a diferença é que em python a tipagem é dinâmica, isso vem do [Duck typing](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)

Segue um exemplo passando uma classe como parâmetro

```
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def setNome(self, nome):
        self.nome = nome

    def setIdade(self, idade):
        self.idade = idade

    def getNome(self):
        return self.nome

    def getIdade(self):
        return self.idade

def meu_metodo(pessoa):
    print(pessoa.getNome())
    print(pessoa.getIdade())

def meu_outro_metodo():
    pessoa = Pessoa()
    pessoa.setNome("Leonardo")
    pessoa.setIdade(23)
    meu_metodo(pessoa)


meu_outro_metodo()
```

No exemplo acima, há uma classe, No 1º método a classe é "instanciada" e tem seus valores setados, após isso é chamado outro método, passando a classe no parâmetro, e nesse outro método, é impresso os valores